# How to include static json data in a React app and minimize loading time?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm making a React app that needs a pretty big (about 1 or 2 MB) json file and I'm trying to figure out how to include the data in a way that will minimize loading time for the user. I'm pretty new at webpack but so far I see two options:

- Add the data to the React source and import it into the jsx
- Put the json in the static file directory and fetch it within the jsx

One other constraint is that multiple pages will be loading the same data, so I was thinking that maybe fetching would be better since the user would have the json cached after the first load.

I'm still pretty new to this and I might be missing something big so I appreciate any info you could give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing a JSON file at build time to bundle it with your code is certainly possible. However I would say keep the JSON as a separate file and fetch it with AJAX. A few reasons why:

1. With caching, if you bundle it with your JS file, any time you make an incremental change to your code you need to re-bundle your code *and* JSON, causing your users to unnecessarily re-download a 1-2 MB file just to get the code updates even if the JSON part hasn't changed. If the files are separate, the browser can cache each independently and only re-download when there's a change.
2. What if users don't need the JSON? Is it 100% necessary in every use-case? Keeping the JSON separate means you can load it only at the actual time it's needed for use instead of preemptively.
3. You mentioned needing the JSON on multiple pages - if it is cached, theoretically they will download it only once even if it's needed across multiple pages.

You may want to read up on [how to leverage caching](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html) so that your server provides the proper headers for browsers to effectively utilize caching.

Comment: That link looks like it's been bought and redirected to some SEO optimisation company